# Replace fenced block with output of command in bash

Tags: text-processing, sed, tree

I'm attempting to replace a "fenced" block of text with the output from the tree command in linux (specifically in a make file).  Here's my input file:

```
some text...
[fencetitle]
----
.
├── file1.txt
└── test
    └── file2.txt

1 directory, 2 files
----
some more text...
```

And I'd like to replace the contents with output from the `tree` command:

```
some text...
[fencetitle]
----
.
├── file1.txt
├── newfile.txt
└── test
    └── file2.txt

1 directory, 3 files
----
some more text...
```

Using the sed command, I can't seem to match using newlines with the line `[fencedtitle]` and `----` to `----`.  I am able to replace text between `[fencedtitle]` and `----` with the following command, however:

```
sed -n '/\[fencedtitle\]/{:a;N;/----/!ba;N;s/.*\n/REPLACEMENT\n/};p' file
```

But I can't seem to then replace REPLACEMENT with the output from the tree command.  Is `sed` the right approach here, or is something else more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
sed -n "/\[fencedtitle\]/{:a;N;/----/!ba;N;s/.*\n/$(tree)\n/};p" file
```

But this will be problematic if the output of `tree` contains characters that are special for regex. If you save the output of `tree` to a file:

```
tree > my-out
```

Then you can read it in sed without too many problems:

```
sed -n '/\[fencetitle\]/{p;n;p;r my-out
:a;n;/^----$/!ba};p' file
```

(Yes, the `r` command does require a new line after it, no commands may follow it on the same line.)

The `p;n;p;` just prints the start of the fence, then we read the file, then we skip everything till the end of the fence.

You can end the line after the `r` command by splitting out the rest into a separate sed expression:

```
sed -ne '/\[fencetitle\]/{p;n;p;r my-out' -e ':a;n;/^----$/!ba};p' file
```

Comment: Great, that seems to do the trick... any idea how I could include that newline in a makefile?

Comment: @JohnEricksen if you split it into two `-e` expressions, you can avoid the newline, see updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a `bash: !ba}: event not found` from the latest command.

Comment: Did you use double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: You're right... seems to work fine in bash, but now in make it's giving me `sed: -e expression #2, char 17: unterminated address regex`.

Comment: What was the exact command you used?

Comment: @JohnEricksen Remember you need to escape `$` in a makefile by using `$$`.  You can also add `-i` to the sed to actually change file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method for above example

```
sed "s/file1.txt/&\n|__newfile/g" example.txt
```

output

```
some text...
[fencetitle]
----
.
├── file1.txt
|__newfile
└── test
    └── file2.txt
```

Comment: I think you took the example too literally; they’re looking for the output of the `tree` command to be put between the bracketed text, not a hard-coded replacement after file1.txt of “newfile”.